# How to put UserDeatils using firebase unique uid in Firebase Realtime Database

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-realtime-database

I wanted to put a unique id every time when users signups into my apps. below is my code attached which is used to store data currently using vehicleNo:

```
FirebaseDatabase db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
DatabaseReference root = db.getReference("Drivers");
DriverModel driverModel = new DriverModel(name,contact,email,licenseNo,vehicleNo,age,bloodGroup,uri.toString(),drowsinessImage,dateTime);
root.child(vehicleNo).setValue(driverModel);
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem. When you step through the code you shared in a debugger, which is the first line that doesnt do what you expect it to do? Is there an error message?

Comment: nope there isn't any error message. The code I provided is saving data in real time database as vehicleno as a parent node. but I want uid as a parent node

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the user is signed in with Firebase Authentication, you can get their UID with:

```
String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
```

Then you can save the data under their UID with:

```
DriverModel driverModel = new DriverModel(name,contact,email,licenseNo,vehicleNo,age,bloodGroup,uri.toString(),drowsinessImage,dateTime);
root.child(uid).setValue(driverModel);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get your key by using `getKey()`. Refer here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#update_specific_fields

```
final String key = root.push().getKey();
```

Next, modify your model class `DriverModel` include the `id`. Example:

```
public class DriverModel{

    //Your others attributes...
    private String id;

    //Do get set also...

}
```

Last, when you want to store data. You can do like this.

```
FirebaseDatabase db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
DatabaseReference root = db.getReference("Drivers");
final String key = root.push().getKey();
DriverModel driverModel = new DriverModel(key, name,contact,email,licenseNo,vehicleNo,age,bloodGroup,uri.toString(),drowsinessImage,dateTime);
root.child(vehicleNo).setValue(driverModel);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are no error messages, simply because you cannot see them. There is nothing in your code that handles errors. To solve this, you have to attach a listener to the `setValue()` operation, to see if something goes wrong. In code, it will be as simple as:

```
root.child(vehicleNo).setValue(driverModel).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            Log.d("TAG", "Data successfully written.");
        } else {
            Log.d("TAG", task.getException().getMessage()); //Never ignore potential errors!
        }
    }
});
```

If you get an error message due to the fact that you have improper security rules, then go to your Firebase console and set them to [allow the write operation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security).